Scrapy Returns Blank Values Inconsistently
I am scraping data from the following URL: https://www.rugbypass.com/live/bristol-vs-leicester/stats/?g=938938
Here is the part of my Scrapy Spider I am concerned with:
match_summary_stats = response.css("#statsSummary_stats > div.stat")

for stat in match_summary_stats:
    stat_name = stat.css("div.mid.smaller::text").get()
    home_value = stat.css("div:nth-child(2)::text").get()
    away_value = stat.css("div:nth-child(4)::text").get()

    home_team_row['stats'][stat_name] = home_value
    away_team_row['stats'][stat_name] = away_value

match_summary_stats contains many divs (most of which function fine) but here are 2 I am iterating over where I see this problem:
<div class="stat">
   <div class="line lh"></div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div class="mid smaller">Penalty Goals</div>
   <div>0</div>
   <div class="line "></div>
</div>
<div class="stat">
   <div class="line lh"></div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div class="mid smaller">Tries</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div class="line "></div>
</div>

When I Yield home_team_row, it looks like below:
{"game_id": "938938", "stats": {"Penalty Goals": "2", "Tries": " "}}

home_team_row should look like this:
{"game_id": "938938", "stats": {"Penalty Goals": "2", "Tries": "3"}}

I am really confused as to why the Tries value is a blank space. Both divs are structured the exact same and Penalty Goals has a value.
For reference, here is my TeamRow() scrapy item:
class TeamRow(scrapy.Item):
    game_id = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags),
        output_processor=TakeFirst()
    )
    team_name = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags),
        output_processor=TakeFirst()
    )
    opposition_team_name = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags),
        output_processor=TakeFirst()
    )
    team_score = scrapy.Field()
    opposition_team_score = scrapy.Field()
    win_or_lose = scrapy.Field()
    stats = scrapy.Field()


I'd suggest a slightly different approach. Here's the full spider:
import scrapy

class RugbySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "rugby"
    start_urls = ["https://www.rugbypass.com/live/bristol-vs-leicester/stats/?g=938938"]

    def parse(self, response):
        game_id = response.css("section.game-header::attr('data-id')").get()

        data = []

        for stat in response.css("#statsSummary_stats .stat"):
            data.append({
                "name": stat.css(".mid::text").get(),
                "home": stat.css(".line + div::text").get(),
                "away": stat.css(".mid + div::text").get()
            })

        yield {
            "game_id": game_id,
            "stats": data
        }

This is what the prettified output looks like:
{
  "game_id": "938938",
  "stats": [
    {
      "name": "Penalty Goals",
      "home": "2",
      "away": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tries",
      "home": "3",
      "away": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Conversions",
      "home": "2",
      "away": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Drop Goals",
      "home": "0",
      "away": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Carries",
      "home": "98",
      "away": "114"
    },
    {
      "name": "Line Breaks",
      "home": "4",
      "away": "3"
    },
    {
      "name": "Turnovers Lost",
      "home": "10",
      "away": "21"
    },
    {
      "name": "Turnovers Won",
      "home": "8",
      "away": "5"
    }
  ]
}

Hope that helps.

Thanks! Ultimately I want to have a dataset with a row for each team so that I can just see the stats for each team and their impact on the result for that team. That's why I've gone with home_team_row and away_team_row

Okay, got it. This approach means that you don't need to worry about checking for non-empty values. Once you have all of the data you can slice and dice it in whatever way you see fit.

I tried doing home_value = stat.css("div:nth-child(2)::text").getall() which gave me home_value = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "3", " ", " "]. I don't know why it did this as it's really not clear from reading the HTML. I did the below instead and it seems to have fixed the issue:
match_summary_stats = response.css("#statsSummary_stats > div.stat")
        for stat in match_summary_stats:
            stat_name = stat.css("div.mid.smaller::text").get()
            home_values = [value.strip() for value in stat.css("div:nth-child(2)::text").getall() if value.strip()]
            away_values = [value.strip() for value in stat.css("div:nth-child(4)::text").getall() if value.strip()]

            # Select the first non-empty value
            home_value = home_values[0] if home_values else None
            away_value = away_values[0] if away_values else None

            home_team_row['stats'][stat_name] = home_value
            away_team_row['stats'][stat_name] = away_value

